# Is there specific grammar used in Newspaper headlines?

Tags: computational-linguistics, grammar

I need to find some general rules used in Newspaper headlines. I will use computational linguistics (nltk python library) to develop classification algorithm to distinguish news and not news by headline.

Answer (score 3):

There are recognisable differences in grammar from normal language, at least in English (eg omission of most articles) but I don't know how systematic the differences are. There are a couple of scholarly works listed in the Wikipedia article on [Headlinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headlinese), but I haven't looked at them myself.